# Bittorrent total size from piece length and info hash

Tags: python, sha1, bittorrent

I am following the unofficial bittorrent spec to write a bittorrent client in python.

I am trying to calculate the total number of pieces in my sample .torrent file, and subsequently the total length of all of the pieces.

The piece length I have retrieved from the metainfo is 2^21. 
And according to the bittorrent spec wiki, the 'pieces' value under the 'info' key is a SHA-1 hash of each piece concatenated as one long byte string.

They say I should get the number of pieces by ceil(total length/piece size), so I'm wondering if I can get the total length from the pieces hash?

I have the pieces hash in a byte string, whose length I received to be 38560. 38560 * 8 bits is much less than 2^21, so I presume I need to decode this in order to calculate the total length?

Comment: I think I goofed, I can find out the total length from the 'length' key in the 'files' key in the 'info' dictionary

Answer (score 0):

The last piece in a torrent is not necessarily the full size of a piece, so you can only extract an approximate total size from the hash list and the piece size. Additionally paddings ([explicit](http://bittorrent.org/beps/bep_0047.html#padding-files) or [implicit](http://bittorrent.org/beps/bep_0052.html#info-dictionary)) can further inflate the byte-ranges covered by the piece hashes.

As you already noticed you can get the accurate total length by summing over the per-file lengths.